# Does the varIdent function, used in LME work fine?

Tags: r, models

I would be glad if somebody could help me to solve this problem. I have data with repeated measurements design, where we tested a reaction of birds (`time.dep`) before and after the infection (`exper`). We have also `FL` (fuel loads, % of lean body mass), fat score and group (Experimental vs Control) as explanatory variables. I decided to use `LME`, because distribution of residuals doesn’t deviate from normality. But there is a problem with homogeneity of residuals. Variances of groups “before” and “after” and also between fat levels differ significantly (Fligner-Killeen test, `p=0.038` and `p=0.01` respectively).

```
   ring    group fat time.dep  FL   exper
1 XZ13125     E   4     0.36 16.295 before
2 XZ13125     E   3     0.32 12.547  after
3 XZ13126     E   3     0.28  7.721 before
4 XZ13127     C   3     0.32  9.157 before
5 XZ13127     C   3     0.40 -1.902  after
6 XZ13129     C   4     0.40 10.382 before
```

After I have selected the random part of the model, which is random-intercept (`~1|ring`), I have applied the weight parameter for both “fat” and “exper” (`varComb(varIdent(form=~1|fat), varIdent(form=~1|exper)`). Now the plot of standardized residuals vs. fitted looks better, but I still get the violation of homogeneity for these variables (same values in fligner test). What do I do wrong?

Comment: hard to tell without a reproducible example.  Are you using `residuals(type="pearson")` ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Probably that was the problem. When I have tried with (type="pearson") everything looks great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common trap in `lme` is that the default is to give raw residuals, i.e. not adjusted for any of the heteroscedasticity (`weights`) or correlation (`correlation`) sub-models that may have been used.  From `?residuals.lme`:

> **type**: an optional character string specifying the type of residuals
>             to be used.  If ‘"response"’, as by default, the “raw”
>             residuals (observed - fitted) are used; else, if ‘"pearson"’,
>             the standardized residuals (raw residuals divided by the
>             corresponding standard errors) are used; else, if
>             ‘"normalized"’, the normalized residuals (standardized
>             residuals pre-multiplied by the inverse square-root factor of
>             the estimated error correlation matrix) are used. Partial
>             matching of arguments is used, so only the first character
>             needs to be provided.

Thus if you want your residuals to be corrected for heteroscedasticity (as included in the model) you need `type="pearson"`; if you want them to be corrected for correlation, you need `type="normalized"`.